# Keep the button Active after reloading the page (using PHP and HTML)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button, bootstrap-4

Is there any way where I can keep the button active after reloading the page? (I am not using any custom CSS, only Bootstrap)
PHP. I am using the buttons as a switch to ON or OFF, in an if condition.

HTML

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 40px;"><p> Show All Conferences </p>
            
<form method="POST">
    <div class="tab-content">
    <button style="margin-left: 35px;" type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button"> On </button>
    <button style="margin-left: -8px;" type="submit" name="submitBtn2" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="button"> Off </button>
</form></div>

</div>



function switch_on_off() 
{
  $dateConf = date('Ymd');
  if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {         
    $dateConf = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submitBtn2'])) { 
    $dateConf = date('Ymd');
  }
  return $dateConf;
}

function get_future_conferences() 
{ 
  $dateConf2 = switch_on_off();
  $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'conference',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'conference_start_date',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'key'     => 'conference_start_date',
        'value'   => $dateConf2,
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
  );
  $conferences = get_posts( $args );
  return $conferences;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use javascript you can use the `session` to do this. After clicking the On/Off button you can save the value (DateTime or etc) in the PHP session and then when you reload the page just check which value is set.